# How do I test for existence of a variable within a function's environment?

Tags: r, function, environment

Given the function `f()` as follows:

```
f = function(a) {
  if(a > 0) b = 2
  c = exists('b')
  return(c)
}
```

How do I specify that the `exists()` function should only search within the function `f`?

With a blank environment, calling `f(-5)` will return `FALSE` as I would like, but if I do

```
b = "hello"
f(-5)
```

then I get `TRUE`. How do I get `f(-5)` to return `FALSE` even if the user has a `b` defined elsewhere in their script outside the function `f`?

I expect this has something to do with the `where` parameter of `exists()` but I can't figure out what is the proper environment to call for this parameter. I still haven't wrapped my head fully around environments in R...

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the `inherits=` parameter of exists. See the `?exists` help page for more info

```
b <- 100
f <- function(a) {
  if(a > 0) b <- 2
  c <- exists('b', inherits=FALSE)
  return(c)
}
f(5)
# [1] TRUE
f(-5)
# [1] FALSE
```